# How to send HTTP request using long Azure JWT token

Tags: api, react-redux, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, maxlength

I'm getting a 400 (Bad Request) when posting a request with JWT as a parameter in the url from React (front-end) to the Web API (.net core Backend). I think because the token is too long and there is a URL limit by browsers..

```
  componentDidMount() {

    const jwtToken = localStorage.getItem('id_token');

    let config = {
        method: 'POST'
    }
    return fetch('http://localhost:33458/api/GetUser/' + jwtToken, config)
        .then(
            (result) => {
                console.log(result);
                //this.setState({
                //    isLoaded: true,
                //    data: result
                //});

            },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
                //this.setState({
                //    isLoaded: true,
                //    error
                //});
            }
        )
}
```

Web API :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("ListUsers/{token}")]
    public List<UserDataModel> GetUser(string token)
    {
       //handle token checking and getting user data
    }
```

How to get around the url max limit ?

Comment: usually the token should not be sent as a url parameter but in the `Authorization` header.

Comment: @jps I'll be thankful if you could provide me with an example for this case

Comment: What example do you need? There should be something in the `fetch` config that let's you set custom headers, add one for `Authorization` with the JWT. Your Web Api should already be setup to use that to auth the user, and if not, consult the docs - it's beyond the scope of this question. Then, just use the principal server-side.

Comment: I added the jwt to the authorization in the header, I'm not sure how to get the header in the web api.

Comment: On WebAPI side you usually use a middleware for token handling and just decorate your Controller with the `[Authorize]` attribute. The middleware then takes care of the token, no need for the parameter in your API anymore. But that's a total different question

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding an Authorization header :

```
headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer" + jwtToken}
```

And then retrieve the value of the Authorization header in the web api with :

```
 string header = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
 string token = header.Remove(0, 6);
```